# Rails - Event Registration Form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to create exactly the same thing explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33206719/event-registration-form).

However, using

```
   def new
      @event = Event.find params[:event_id]
      @registration = @event.registration.new
   end
```

I get an 'undefined method':

```
Started GET "/events/1/registrations/new" for ::1 at 2016-07-22 13:59:08 +0200
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
Processing by RegistrationsController#new as HTML
  Parameters: {"event_id"=>"1"}
  Event Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "events".* FROM "events" WHERE "events"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 30ms (ActiveRecord: 0.5ms)

NoMethodError (undefined method `registration' for #<Event:0x00000003e58bb8>
Did you mean?  registrations
               registrations=):
  app/controllers/registrations_controller.rb:4:in `new'
```

What am I missing?

Comment: what is the association betwee event and registrations

Comment: Did you mean registrations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have followed this

```
#app/models/event.rb
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :registrations
end

#app/models/registration.rb
class Registration < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :event
end
```

You need to change `registration` to `registrations`

```
def new
  @event = Event.find params[:event_id]
  @registration = @event.registrations.new
end
```

> NoMethodError (undefined method `registration' for #< Event:0x00000003e58bb8>

You have solution in your question itself ;)

> Did you mean?  registrations

Comment: Thank you Deepak. I modified that and now I get 'NoMethodError in Registrations#new'. My routes.rb says `  Rails.application.routes.draw do
    resources :events do
    resources :registrations
  end`

Comment: post the log please

Comment: ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `registrations_path' for #<#<Class:0x00000003ef1548>:0x00000003ece598>):
    1: <%= form_for(@registration) do |f| %>

Comment: check your routes using rake routes

Comment: I think it should be form_for(:event, @registration) if you are using nested routes

Comment: Awesome, that solved it. I just had to add the square brackets: `<%= form_for([:event, @registration]) do |f| %>` Thank you!